# Polymorphism and callbacks, what is happening here?

Tags: c++

I moved to a new Uni. In my old program we had a heavy focus on Java however in the new Uni we have a strong focus on C++ and no introductory class. I'm going over C++ tutorials to get familiar but I would like to finish this task.

Basically we need to write a program that will calculate numerical derivative which is not a problem I just don't fully understand the given code:

We need to use two concepts: polymorphism and callback

Code:

```
double myfunction(const double x){
...
}

class Der{
...
};

int main(){
    double x, h;

    Der::derivative(Der(),x,h)
    Der::derivative(myfunction,x,h)

    derivative(Der(),x,h)
    derivative(myfunction,x,h)

    return 0;
}
```

Ok so first two calls I don't understand what `Der()` means what are we passing here does not look like an instance of an object. I'm familiar with passing functions as arguments but not completely sure why is either object or function being passed shouldn't the method `derivative` calculate it from `x, h` arguments.

In second two lines I'm not sure what's the point ? If I need another `derivative` function than what's the purpose of `myFunction` ?

Comment: Looks like they're trying to teach something about the scope resolution operator.  Without seeing the definition of the Der class it looks like it might have a static function named derivative which has (at least) two overloads.  One that accepts a Der object (which is constructed with the Der()) and one that accepts a function pointer (myfunction).  At a guess there is also a derivative function with two prototypes within the file scope of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what Der() means.

`Der` it's the name of the class. You are calling `derivative()` of class `Der`. You need to do this because there is no instance of class `Der` created (hint: that means that `derivative()` is a static function (read more [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/))!!).

> If I need another derivative function than what's the purpose of myFunction?

We can't tell for sure, since you show no implementation, but `derivative()` seems like a function who will take another function as a parameter and execute it, thus resulting in different operations.

---

> I know Der() is class not sure why it's being passed to Der::derivative(..) and why as Der() and not a variable that holds an instance of it.

Well, `Der()` is a constructor, you need to pass it as this, since `derivative()` takes a function as first parameter. Which is the purpose? Unknown with what we know now.

Comment: I know Der() is class not sure why it's being passed to Der::derivative(..) and why as Der() and not a variable that holds an instance of it.